# string replacement based on part of text in php

Tags: php, string, replace

I wonder if i can include square brackets using some string replacement functions. For example a function need to find the exactly string of

```
param\":{
```

So the original string

```
param\":{this_is_long_string}
```

Will become

```
param\":[{this_is_long_string}]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `preg_replace()` function: https://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

regex example: https://regex101.com/r/RL8gb9/3

```
<?php
$re = '/":(.*)/';
$str = 'param\":{this_is_long_string}';

preg_match($re, $str, $matches);

var_dump(preg_replace($re, '":['.$matches[1].']', $str));

//output
//string(31) "param\":[{this_is_long_string}]"
```

example:
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c844e5c43a337ba545403661c23b722352ae04d9

if it always start with `param\":` you can consider (dirty way) to use `str_replace()` like this:

```
$string = 'param\":{this_is_long_string}';
$new_string = str_replace('param\":', 'param\":[', string) . ']';
```

Comment: Hi, can you provide example in preg_replace()? Because it not started with param\":

There are string before param and after the } character.Thanks

Comment: I've edited my answer, hope it fit in what you need

Comment: Hi, the coding is working for above $string, but since the actual $string is very long (decoded json) e.g.  

"country\":\"France\",\"param\":{this_is_long_string}}]

So if you can use preg_replace() to solve it?

Comment: please provide me a full example (maybe edit your answer); i'll help you asap

Comment: hi andreah, thanks for your help, i have replaced the $string, please refer to http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f3333faf0cafe7b82fc42efbbabd6697bff14bf6

Comment: Ok, can I ask you why you need brackets in every values?

Comment: Hi andreah, i like to include a square bracket for the single element, in this case the single element is {\"ref\":\"AB17-96SD\",\"qty\":\"1\"}. I think format the string at output would be easier. Because the whole string is long so i just include part of the string. Thanks

Comment: Yes, i've understood that, but I wonder if you could use a different approch for that. For example, when you decode the json can't you use a trick like this? `$value = (array)$value;`. Cast your string as array, works fit your specific case?

Comment: Hi @andreah, the replace string method may not suitable for my question, because i thought it is simple to just replace the string. But the original issue is to manipulate the format of JSON. I created a question here:

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56514045/force-to-add-array-into-single-element-of-json-in-php-integrated-to-plugin) 

Basically i accepted your answer that what i have asked in this post. thanks

Answer (score 0):

A simple `str_replace` and a little concatenation will work given your description of the problem.

```
$startvar = 'param\":{this_is_long_string}';
$look4    = 'param\":{';
$changed  = str_replace($look4,$look4 . '[',$startvar) . ']';
echo $changed;
```

Comment: I need to tweak a bit to achieve the goal but the square bracket at the end is not working. For the following code 

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a6a0802bc7af3e1ed0cb59972cc2ebe32627d32d

it output

xxxparam\":[{this_is_long_string}xxx] 
 
desired output:

xxxparam\":[{this_is_long_string}]xxx

Comment: It appears to be there when I run what you posted.